# Basics of ScrollView in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I started with a view based template where I added a scroll view from IB in view Controller.xib

Then in MyViewController.m in method

`- (void)viewDidLoad`

1)added 5 imageview with images in that with proper x and y

2)Then I set the contentSize

3)then `[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
NSLog(@"inside DID SCROLL");
NSLog(@"The scroll is %@", sender);
NSLog(@"The scroll.contentOffset.x is %@", [sender contentSize]);
}
```

Now if contentoffset is (10, 0) it crashes straight away, but if contentoffset is (0, 0) then it calls `didScroll` and then crashes on [sender contentSize]

What am I doing wrong, I'm sure it's a very basic error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its a basic error. *contentSize* is a *struct* which you can not print as object by using `%@`. You can print is as,

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize([scroll contentSize]));
```

Or as,

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", scroll.contentSize.width, scroll.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

That worked but now i will have to parse string to get value,

it there any other way out, i wantd to get x coordinate f offset.

Thanks